# Push Notification with GetStream Notification feed

Tags: getstream-io

We are currently using `getStream` in our react web application for notification feed. It is working fine.

We are now planning to use it in our react native mobile app as well. We would like to show a notification (in the top tray or drawer) whenever there is a notification received by a user, similar to how we get in whatsapp or telegram

Does anyone know how this can be achieved. Couldn't find anything about this in their docs. I can see that they provide this functionality with `Stream Chat`

PS: We are able to get the notifications in the app but we would like to show the notification in the top tray as well so that the user knows he/she has received notifications without opening the app.

Regards,
Varun

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is about offering Push Notifications for your application. Stream Feeds does not currently implement Push Notifications out of the box so you will have to implement them in your application yourself. One common approach is to use notification webhooks where you have the webhook trigger a push notification for the user from your application's back end infrastructure.

I hope that is helpful.

Best,
Grant